# Get input from user

Tags: java

I have tried to get user input with scanner and if user press enter then proceed to next input statement. but it print all at once.

```
public class MainRDS 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String path;
        String name;
        String ext;
        String date;

        System.out.println("Directory search by path, name, extension, content and date.");
        System.out.print("\nEnter Starting directory for the search (link c:"+"\\"+"temp) : ");
        path = in.next();

        System.out.print("\nEnter the file name (like myFile or enter for all) : ");

        if((name = in.nextLine()).length() > 0)
        System.out.print("\nEnter the file extenstion (like txt or enter for all) : ");

        if((ext = in.nextLine()).length() > 0)
        System.out.print("\nEnter last modified date (like 11/21/2012 or enter for any) : ");

        date = in.nextLine();
    }
}
```

output :

```
Directory search by path, name, extension, content and date.

Enter Starting directory for the search (link c:\temp) : c:

Enter the file name (like myFile or enter for all) : myfile

Enter last modified date (like 11/21/2012 or enter for any) :
```

required output:

```
Directory search by path, name, extension, content and date.  
Enter starting directory for the search (like c:\temp): c:\temp 
Enter the file name (like myFile or enter for all):  
Enter the file extension (like txt or enter for all): txt 
Enter content to search for (like comp121 or enter for any):  
Enter last modified date (like 11/21/2013 or enter for any): 11/1/2011
```

Comment: Do you think, that if you ask same question twice, something will change?

Comment: There WAS a working answer in your last asked question. You just being impatient and making a new question already without checking anything.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `\n` and use println. Lets me know if it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use in.nextLine() instead of in.next().

Comment: I try that but then it also skip input statements